# How can I type parameterize a struct that doesn't use that type directly?

Tags: rust

In the past this code compiled, but recently it no longer is accepted (I believe since [RFC 738](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0738-variance.md)). I want to type-parameterize the `VertexBuffer`, but it doesn't actually hold any vertices, rather the GPU holds the vertices, and the struct only holds an OpenGL `buffer_id`:

```
pub struct VertexBuffer<V: Vertex> {
    buffer_id: GLuint,
    num_vertices: usize,
}
```

The `new` function fills the buffer:

```
impl<V: Vertex> VertexBuffer<V> {
    pub fn new(data: &Vec<V>) -> VertexBuffer<V>
    {
        let buffer_id = unsafe {
            let mut id: GLuint = 0;
            gl::GenBuffers(1, &mut id);
            gl::BindBuffer(gl::ARRAY_BUFFER, id);
            gl::BufferData(gl::ARRAY_BUFFER,
                (mem::size_of::<V>() * data.len()) as GLsizeiptr,
                 mem::transmute(&data[0]),
                 gl::STATIC_DRAW);
            id
        };

        VertexBuffer {
            buffer_id: buffer_id,
            num_vertices: data.len(),
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

I now get these errors:

```
src/vertex_buffer.rs:10:25: 10:26 error: parameter `V` is never used
src/vertex_buffer.rs:10 pub struct VertexBuffer<V: Vertex> {

src/vertex_buffer.rs:10:25: 10:26 help: consider removing `V` or using a marker such as `core::marker::PhantomData`
src/vertex_buffer.rs:10 pub struct VertexBuffer<V: Vertex> {
```

FYI, other functions in the impl such as pre_render() and post_render() use the V type to do their work, calling things like

```
let attribute_data = Vertex::attribute_data(None::<V>);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown enough code to rule this out, so I'd suggest moving your type to the function(s):

```
impl VertexBuffer {
    pub fn new<V: Vertex>(data: &Vec<V>) -> VertexBuffer<V> {
        let buffer_id = unsafe {
            let mut id: GLuint = 0;
            gl::GenBuffers(1, &mut id);
            gl::BindBuffer(gl::ARRAY_BUFFER, id);
            gl::BufferData(gl::ARRAY_BUFFER,
                (mem::size_of::<V>() * data.len()) as GLsizeiptr,
                 mem::transmute(&data[0]),
                 gl::STATIC_DRAW);
            id
        };

        VertexBuffer {
            buffer_id: buffer_id,
            num_vertices: data.len(),
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

If you do need to use [PhantomData](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html), try something like:

```
struct VertexBuffer<V> {
    buffer_id: u32, // or whatever
    num_vertices: u32, // or whatever
    marker: std::marker::PhantomData<V>,
}

impl<V: Vertex> VertexBuffer<V> {
    pub fn new(data: &Vec<V>) -> VertexBuffer<V> {
        let buffer_id = unsafe {
            let mut id: GLuint = 0;
            gl::GenBuffers(1, &mut id);
            gl::BindBuffer(gl::ARRAY_BUFFER, id);
            gl::BufferData(gl::ARRAY_BUFFER,
                (mem::size_of::<V>() * data.len()) as GLsizeiptr,
                 mem::transmute(&data[0]),
                 gl::STATIC_DRAW);
            id
        };

        VertexBuffer {
            buffer_id: buffer_id,
            num_vertices: data.len(),
            marker: std::marker::PhantomData,
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: I considered that.  However, other functions in the impl of VertexBuffer use the type parameter as well, and I would hope the type system would catch mismatches when a VertexBuffer was created with one Vertex type, and used with another.
I'm trying your 2nd suggestion...

Comment: @AntManelope Sounds like you need the `PhantomData` then. Is your struct responsible for freeing the buffer when it's done? Can you ever return one of the `Vertex`es?

Comment: Yes it implements the Drop trait to free the buffer.  A Vertex is never returned, but functions on the specific V type are called (modified original question to show).